# How to set javadoc parameters in netbeans

Tags: java, javadoc, netbeans-7

I have just found out that javadoc is yet another program that is broken when it comes to Turkish locale and [it won't fix.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=223794) Luckily, there is a `-locale` option that I could set from command line. However, I don't want to work with cmd.exe. Is there a way to change parameters passed from netbeans to javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Maven with Netbeans then you're using Netbeans' own Ant build scripts.

In the `nbproject` folder inside your project you'll find a `project.properties` file that has a `javadoc.encoding` entry.

Comment: encoding is not locale.

Answer (score 0):

In **build-impl.xml**, add the locale option:

> <javadoc ... **locale="en_US"**>

Or, in project properties/build/documenting/add additional options:

> **-locale "en_US"**

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans 9, you can right-click on the project and select Properties then select Documenting.  You can add javadoc options (e.g. -locale) in the box labeled 'Additional Javadoc Options:'.  I don't have NetBeans 7 to verify it works the same way in that version.

In version 12, right-click on the project, select Properties then expand 'Build' then select Documenting.  There you will find the 'Additional Javadoc Options:'.

Comment: can't find "Documenting" it there today